# Is the address of a std::array guaranteed the same as its data?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, stdarray

`std::array` is ... (quoting from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)):

> This container is an aggregate type with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array `T[N]` as its only non-static data member.

Does that imply that the address of an array is always the same as the address of its first element, i.e. `data()`?

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::array<int,6> x{};
    std::cout << &x << "\n";
    std::cout << x.data();
}
```

Possible output:

```
0x7ffc86a62860
0x7ffc86a62860
```

And if yes, is this of any use? Is the following allowed?

```
int* p = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&x);
for (int i=0;i<6;++i){ std::cout << p[i]; }
```

Comment: why would you want to do `reinterpret_cast<int*>(&x)` rather than just `x.data()`?

Comment: C has a rule that the address of any `struct` is equal to the address of its first member, and that a pointer to one can be safely cast to the other.  Does C++ have the same rule for `class`es?  I am not quite sure where to look in the standard.

Comment: Actually I'm not seeing "only non-static data member" in the standard; the standard doesn't seem to rule out other members. Did cppreference make it up?

Comment: @NateEldredge static members, whether data or methods or whatever, don't take up any space in an object's allocated storage. Only non-static data members do.

Comment: You're making an assumption about the internal layout of a class defined by the standard. As is usual for these things, the standard does not explicitly state what that internal layout should be (nor can I see any mention that it only has one data member).

Comment: @AlanBirtles last part isnt well phrased, I am not actually asking if this is of use, but it is just curiosity

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I admit I took cppref for granted. If you can quote the standard and it doesnt say that the array is the only data member of an `array`, that would already disproof my assumptions

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Right, I know that.  What I'm saying is that the Standard doesn't seem to forbid `std::array<T>` from having additional non-static data members, so I am unclear why cppreference asserts that the `T[N]` array is the only one.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Quote something that isn't there? I dunno, but you can look at one of the [online](https://eel.is/c++draft/array) copies of the standard.

Comment: _Is the following allowed?_ Not necessarily. If `std::array<T, N>` contains only a member of type `T[N]`, which is, I think, a typical implementation, your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: This may be false when `N` is zero, i.e. `std::array<int,0>` ([example](https://ideone.com/auLya2))

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Technically, a `std::array` object may have padding at the beginning, in which case the data will be at a higher address than the `std::array` object. Only for *standard-layout classes* is there a guarantee that the object itself has the same address as the first non-static data member.

There is no guarantee in the standard that `std::array<T, N>` is standard-layout, even if `T` is `int` or something like that. All *reasonable* implementations of `std::array<T, N>` will have a single non-static data member of type `T[N]`, no virtual functions, and at most a single inheritance chain with no virtual base classes, which would mean they would be standard-layout as long as `T` itself is standard-layout. Plus, even if `T` is not standard-layout, the compiler is not likely to insert padding at the beginning of the `std::array` object.

So, while an assumption that a `std::array<T, N>` object has the same address as the first `T` object it contains is not portable, it is basically guaranteed in practice. And you can add a `static_assert(sizeof(std::array<T, N>) == sizeof(T[N]));` just to be sure that, if someone ever tries to build your code on an exotic implementation where it isn't the case, they'll know it's not supported.

Comment: The standard does say `std::array` is an aggregate, though. So, doesn't that imply standard-layout?

Comment: @RemyLebeau aggregate and standard layout are different things.  You can have a non-standard layout aggregate.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think almost, but not quite. An aggregate class could have multiple (public) base class subobjects of the same type. A standard-layout class can't. Of course, no reasonable implementation would do something like this in the case of `std::array`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I think it's an aggregate in the sense that it is a class with no user-declared or inherited constructors, no private or protected direct non-static data members, etc.  But that says nothing about what its members actually are.  I think the standard would allow `class std::array<T,N> { public: int miscellaneous_junk; T actual_array[N]; };`

Comment: @NateEldredge That particular implementation wouldn't be conforming. The miscellaneous junk members would interfere with aggregate initialization.

Comment: _That particular implementation wouldn't be conforming_ You forgot to add «if the impl. doesn't have a special initialization rule for `std::array`». [An `array` is an aggregate that can be list-initialized with up to `N` elements whose types are convertible to `T`.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/array#overview-2) As long as the impl. supports this, the content of `std::array` can haz any junk in the beginning. Like `std::complex` array reinterpretation as two times longer array of `float`/`double` is a «violation» of [expr.add]/4, an impl. can «violate» [dcl.init.aggr] for `array`