is aliasing a plain array to an `std::array` not UB
I proposed several techniques to answer to Idiom for initializing an std::array using a generator function taking the index?.
A classical way to answer would be to use std::index_sequence-based solution but op had two constraints:

it should work with a non default-constructible type
it should work for large std::array sizes, larger than what common std::index_sequence implementations are supporting.

Using std::array for large array instead of a std::vector is debatable but it's not the "assignment".
Some of my answers are relying on creating a temporary raw storage where I'm building objects in place and then I'm aliasing the memory to a pointer to std::array that I'm using to move-initialized a new array.
I have concerns about the legality of the code, that can be pinned down to:
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

// allocate storage for an std::array and construct its object inplace before
// moving it to destination
template<typename T, std::size_t N, typename Gen) std::array<T,N> make_array(gen)
{
    // checking std::array layout
    static_assert(sizeof(std::array<T, N>) == N * sizeof(T));
    alignas(T) unsigned char storage[N * sizeof(T)];
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        new (storage + i * sizeof(T)) T(gen(i));
    }
    // aliasing from array of bytes
    // is this legal?
    return std::move(*reinterpret_cast<std::array<T, N>*>(storage));
}

// allocate storage for an std::array inside a vector and construct its object
// inplace before moving it to destination
template<typename T, std::size_t N, typename Gen) std::array<T,N> make_array(gen)
{
    // checking std::array layout
    static_assert(sizeof(std::array<T, N>) == N * sizeof(T));
    auto v = std::vector<T>{};
    v.reserve(N);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        v.emplace_back(gen(i))
    };
    // aliasing from array of T
    // is this legal?
    return std::move(
        *reinterpret_cast<std::array<T, N>*>(v.data());
}

playground
Are the return statements above valid?
And, if no, is there a way to solve the issue?
Wording from the standard whould be appreciate to justify the answer(s).

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69500721/is-the-address-of-a-stdarray-guaranteed-the-same-as-its-data

@463035818_is_not_an_ai this is why I've got a static_assert at the beginning. If the assertion does not hold, I don't think you can alias a plain array to an std::array (you'll be missing implementation-specific data).

hm ok i missed that. In case you pass the assert I don't know how this could possibly fail. And I think it is legal, but don't count on that ;)

The second one is clearly UB. In contrast to the first variant, there is no guarantee about implicit object creation needed to get a std::array in the first place.

You should also check that alignof(std::array<T, N>) == alignof(T). There is no requirement in the standard for it to hold. If it doesn't hold, then the pointer will be misaligned for the reinterpret_cast and again UB.

And in the first variant there is a std::launder missing after the reinterpret_cast.

@user17732522 I never fully understand the role of std::launder. I see it should be used  for Obtaining a pointer to an object created by placement new from a pointer to an object providing storage for that object.. So probably OK for the first exemple but why shouldn't it be required also for the std::vector buffer (it probably uses placement new also, no?)

@Oersted The vector case has undefined behavior anyway, because there is no implicit object creation, so I didn't mention it. std::launder doesn't cause the object creation. The fact that you are starting the lifetime of an array of unsigned char specifically is what causes implicit object creation allowing this to work because std::array is an aggregate type without user-declared destructor, therefore an implicit-lifetime type that can be implicitly created. std::launder is needed to get a pointer to that already-created object starting from a pointer into the storage-providing array.

@user17732522 Thanks for the clarification on the first version. For the std::vector I'm not sure to get it correctly. Is it that implicit lifetime does not kick in because the std::vector is a (dynamic) array of T not of bytes and thus, even despite the explicit object construction, the rule of implicit array creation does not apply?

@Oersted std::vector will use std::allocator_traits::allocate to obtain memory. Firstly it is unspecified when and how std::vector will use the allocation. If it was to e.g. access the bytes of the memory as a different type first, implicit object creation can't help you anymore. And secondly, std::allocatot_traits::allocate is only specified to implicitly create an array of T. It doesn't implicitly create any other objects, in particular not std::array.

@Oersted You only get assured implicit object creation that you need here if you either use an array of unsigned char or std::byte whose lifetime you started and that hasn't been used as any other type beforehand (including std::byte and unsigned char itself), or if you take memory directly from a function that implicitly creates objects, e.g. std::malloc or operator new, again without any intermediate use of other type in the memory.

@user17732522 Thanks again. Do you mean that as soon as I've created objects in a storage I cannot reuse it later? Or if I destroy the objects created there (ending their lifetime), for instance through an explicit destructor call, the storage can be reused again?

@Oersted You can reuse it, but only by explicit creation of the objects you need with new. You can't rely on e.g. a std::array<U,10> object being created implicitly after you have already used the allocation/array to store a std::array<T,10>. However, you can use a function that is specified to implicitly-create objects to "reset" that. For example memcpy and std::start_lifetime_as are such functions.

I think this is legal post C++20, because an instance of std::array<T, N> is implicitly created, however cppreference's example for std::start_lifetime_as has comments claiming similar constructs are UB.
However, if you have C++20 then you can use std::bit_cast, which is much less suspicious than the reinterpret_cast:
// allocate storage for an std::array and construct its object inplace before
// moving it to destination
template<typename T, std::size_t N, typename Gen) std::array<T,N> make_array(Gen gen)
{
    // checking std::array layout
    static_assert(sizeof(std::array<T, N>) == N * sizeof(T));
    alignas(T) unsigned char storage[N * sizeof(T)];
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        new (storage + i * sizeof(T)) T(gen(i));
    }
    // Explicit From to ensure no array to pointer decay
    return std::bit_cast<std::array<T, N>, unsigned char[N * sizeof(T)]>(storage);
}

If you have C++23 you can potentially do better (unless the copy in bit_cast is elided) with std::start_lifetime_as if T is an ImplicitLifetimeType:
// allocate storage for an std::array and construct its object inplace before
// moving it to destination
template<typename T, std::size_t N, typename Gen) std::array<T,N> make_array(Gen gen)
{
    // checking std::array layout
    static_assert(sizeof(std::array<T, N>) == N * sizeof(T));
    alignas(T) unsigned char storage[N * sizeof(T)];
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        new (storage + i * sizeof(T)) T(gen(i));
    }
    return *std::start_lifetime_as<std::array<T, N>>(storage);
}


The comment at cppreference is specifically about the assumption that bytes that have been written to the storage would result in a corresponding value of the implicitly-created object. The implicitly-created object would have an indeterminate value instead. In OP's case that's not an issue because they are creating new (transparently-replaceable) T objects in the array anyway. But either way, at least the std::launder is missing in OP's reinterpret_cast approach.

Both std::bit_cast and std::start_lifetime_as will limit OP's approach to trivially-copyable/implicit-lifetime T. The reinterpret_cast approach doesn't have this restriction.

(Lack of) implicit lifetime types are a defect in all standard versions (i.e., unsigned char storage[N*sizeof(T)] can implicitly create objects in all C++ versions, not just C++20). And for std::array<T, N> to be implicit lifetime (for N>0), T has to be trivially copy- or move- constructible and trivially destructible, it is not enough for T to be implicit-lifetime (e.g., std::string[5] is implicit-lifetime, but std::array<std::string[5], 4> is not implicit-lifetime)

@Artyer std::array is an aggregate class with implicitly-declared destructor, so it is always going to the implicit-lifetime. But of course std::start_lifetime_as also needs it to be trivially-copyable. Otherwise the result has unspecified value.

@user17732522 Oh I missed the aggregate case. So the array of char will always create the std::array, and you don't have to mess around with std::start_lifetime_as at all

std::bit_cast creates a new object (different memory location) whose value representation is the same as the one of a From object? (padding bits being unspecified). Bit, in this case, it should be elided by RVO?

std::start_lifetime_as is unclear for me. Why need it for implicit lifetime object. It sounds contradictory to explicitely start lifetime of implicit lifetime objects. Besides, it says that it also implicitly creates nested objects. But what if these objects are not implicit lifetime (see comment about std::string for instance?

@Oersted yes, we are hoping for some elision in bit_cast. std::start_lifetime_as can re-use more types of storage, and side-steps any funny business with CWG1997 in this case
